# Excel VBA For Loop is ignored without warnings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code as follow:

```
Dim index, find As Integer
    find = 0
    index = MoldWidthComboBox.Value * 10 + MoldLengthComboBox.Value / 10
    'MsgBox (index)
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Set Range1 = Range("B2:B71")
    Dim RowNum As Integer
    For RowNum = 2 To Range1.Count
        If Cells(RowNum, 2) = index Then
            designtable1.Configuration = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
            find = 1
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next RowNum
    
    If find = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No any moldbase configurations is found")
        MsgBox (index)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Problem: The code runs without any error warning but it seemed like my For loop is ignored in the running process, which cause errors to my big program. I can't make out why. Please help me.

Note: The problem came up when I added some lines of code in the original one, which run well and look as follow:

```
Dim index As Integer
index = MoldWidthComboBox.Value * 10 + MoldLengthComboBox.Value / 10
Dim Range1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("B2:B71")
Dim RowNum As Integer
For RowNum = 2 To Range1.Count
        If Cells(RowNum, 2) = index Then
            designtable1.Configuration = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        End If
Next RowNum
```

Comment: What do you get if you put a debug.print range1.count immediately before the for statement.  Also, I'd strongly recommend that you install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and to take a look at the code inspections.

Comment: Impossible to say without having your data. Have you debugged your code (execute it step by step, using F8)? Also, as you don't qualify `Cells` and `Range` (you don't tell VBA which worksheet you want to access), VBA will work on the current active sheet (ActiveSheet) - maybe not the sheet you expect.

Comment: You probably need to define index as Integer and use `index = Round( MoldWidthComboBox.Value * 10 + MoldLengthComboBox.Value / 10,0)`. Also `Range("B2:B71").Count` is 70 so you are only looping down to row 70.

Comment: To add to the comment of @CDP1802, `Dim index, find As Integer` only declares `find` as an Integer. `index` is implicitly declared to be `Variant`.

Comment: Are you aware that `Range1.Count = 70`? To get the **first worksheet row** you can use `Range1.Row` (you are explicitly using 2) while to get the **last worksheet row** you can use `Range1.Row + Range1.Rows.Count - 1` which in this particular case boils down to `2 + Range1.Rows.Count - 1 = .Range1.Rows.Count + 1` (not recommended). What is the purpose of the `Find` variable?

Comment: @FunThomas yes, I opened only a Workbook with a Worksheet at the time of running. So I think it's unnecessary to tell VBA which worksheet in this case.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the Find variable acts as a signal allowing to exit the loop right after a match is found.

Comment: @freeflow  The problem is that my For loop is almost ingored. The Find variable is still equal to 0 although there is a match as expected through the loop.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thank you for let me know, I will fix it!

Answer (score 1):

### A VBA Lookup: `For...Next` vs `Application.Match`

**A Quick Fix (`For...Next`)**

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

Dim MoldIndex As Double
MoldIndex = MoldWidthComboBox.Value * 10 + MoldLengthComboBox.Value / 10
'MsgBox (MoldIndex)

Dim rgIndex As Range: Set rgIndex = ws.Range("B2:B71")

Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long

With rgIndex
    FirstRow = .Row
    LastRow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
End With

Dim r As Long, IsFound As Boolean

For r = FirstRow To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(r, "B").Value = MoldIndex Then
        designtable1.Configuration = ws.Cells(r, "A").Value
        IsFound = True
        Exit For ' if you only need the first occurrence
    End If
Next r

If IsFound Then
    IsFound = False ' reset if the whole thing is in a loop
Else
    MsgBox "No moldbase configurations found for '" & MoldIndex & "'.", _
        vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

**An Improvement (`Application.Match`)**

- Note that this works only if you're after the first occurring match.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

Dim MoldIndex As Double
MoldIndex = MoldWidthComboBox.Value * 10 + MoldLengthComboBox.Value / 10
'MsgBox (MoldIndex)

Dim rgIndex As Range: Set rgIndex = ws.Range("B2:B71")

Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(MoldIndex, rgIndex, 0)

If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
    designtable1.Configuration _
        = rgIndex.Cells(rIndex).EntireRow.Columns("A").Value
Else
    MsgBox "No moldbase configurations found for '" & MoldIndex & "'.", _
        vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```